# JSF button to dynamically add row to table also inserts extra table

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am using Primefaces 5.2 on an internal network that uses IE11 in compatibility mode.  I have a button and a table.  When I press the button I get a new row in the table just fine but I also get an empty table `<table></table>` inserted between the button and the table.  This happened each and every time I press the button - three presses three unwanted empty tables.

Sanitized JSF source follows:

```
<tr>
   <td>
      <h:outputText value="#{enr['birth.date']}"/>*:
   </td>
   <td>
      <p:calendar id="birthDate" value="#{II.birthdate}" mode="popup" showOn="button" popupIconOnly="true" pattern="yyyy-MM-dd" mask="9999-99-99" maxdate="#{UserBean.currentDate}" yearrange="c-120" navigator="true" showButtonPanel="true" required="true" requiredMessage="#{enr['missing.required.field']}: #{enr['birth.date']}" tabindex="4"/>
      <p:tooltip for="birthDate" value="yyyy-MM-dd" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade" />
   </td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td>
      <h:outputText value="#{enr['other.last.names']}"/> / <h:outputText value="#{enr['maiden.name']}"/>
   </td>
   <td>
      <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-plus" title="Icon Only" tabindex="5" immediate="true">
         <f:ajax listener="#{II.addOtherName()}" immediate="true" render="otherNameFields"/>
      </p:commandButton>
      <h:dataTable id="otherNameFields" value="#{II.otherNames}" var="otherNameField">
         <h:column size="30" maxlength="50">
            <h:inputText value="#{otherNameField.otherName}" tabindex="6">
               <f:ajax event="change" listener="#{II.populateName()}" immediate="true" render="otherNameFields" />
            </h:inputText>
         </h:column>
         <h:column>
            <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-trash" title="Icon Only" immediate="true" tabindex="6">
               <f:ajax listener="#{II.deleteOtherName(otherNameField)}" immediate="true" render="otherNameFields" />
            </p:commandButton>
         </h:column>
      </h:dataTable>
   </td>
</tr>
```

Here is the generated output I see in the DOM Explorer:

```
<tr>
   <td>
      <button name="dataForm:j_id605621413_2_2c601363" tabindex="5" title="Icon Only" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-icon-only" id="dataForm:j_id605621413_2_2c601363" role="button" aria-disabled="false" onclick="PrimeFaces.bcn(this,event,[function(event){jsf.ajax.request('dataForm:j_id605621413_2_2c601363',event,{render:'dataForm:otherNameFields','javax.faces.behavior.event':'click'})},function(event){PrimeFaces.ab({s:&quot;dataForm:j_id605621413_2_2c601363&quot;});return false;}]);" type="submit"><span class="ui-button-icon-left ui-icon ui-c ui-icon-plus"></span><span class="ui-button-text ui-c">ui-button</span></button>
      <table></table> <!-- the unwanted table element -->
      <table id="dataForm:otherNameFields">
         <tbody id="dataForm:otherNameFields:tbody_element">
            <tr><td><input name="dataForm:otherNameFields:0:j_id605621413_2_2c6013ca" tabindex="6" id="dataForm:otherNameFields:0:j_id605621413_2_2c6013ca" onchange="jsf.ajax.request('dataForm:otherNameFields:0:j_id605621413_2_2c6013ca',event,{render:'dataForm:otherNameFields','javax.faces.behavior.event':'change'})" type="text" value=""></td><td><button name="dataForm:otherNameFields:0:j_id605621413_2_2c601007" tabindex="6" title="Icon Only" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-icon-only" id="dataForm:otherNameFields:0:j_id605621413_2_2c601007" role="button" aria-disabled="false" onclick="PrimeFaces.bcn(this,event,[function(event){jsf.ajax.request('dataForm:otherNameFields:0:j_id605621413_2_2c601007',event,{render:'dataForm:otherNameFields','javax.faces.behavior.event':'click'})},function(event){PrimeFaces.ab({s:&quot;dataForm:otherNameFields:0:j_id605621413_2_2c601007&quot;});return false;}]);" type="submit"><span class="ui-button-icon-left ui-icon ui-c ui-icon-trash"></span><span class="ui-button-text ui-c">ui-button</span></button></td></tr>
</tbody></table>
   </td>
</tr>
```

Any

Comment: What if you turn off compatibility mode?

Comment: I'll try that to see if it works and gives me more info on the cause.  Unfortunately it is not a solution I can use - I am working on a government project and compatibility mode is a standard employed throughout this sector.

Comment: You can turn it of in pages by adding meta tags in your html... search the internet about this